# Получение списка пользователей, поставивших реакцию в группе телеграма, используя pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

Мне необходимо получить список пользователей, поставивших реакцию в группе телеграма. Библиотека pyrogram, не telethon. В документации нашел только GetMessagesReactions, но не могу понять, как это использовать.

```
async for message in client.get_chat_history(channel.id, limit=num_messages):
    r_peer = await client.resolve_peer(channel.id)
    reaction = GetMessagesReactions(peer=r_peer, id=[message.id])
    print(reaction)
```

Код возвращает

```
{
    "_": "functions.messages.GetMessagesReactions",
    "peer": {
        "_": "types.InputPeerChat",
        "chat_id": 988547793
    },
    "id": [
        25281
    ]
}
```

Подскажите, как это можно использовать правильно, или, возможно, есть какой-то другой способ  получить информацию о том, кто ставит реакции.

Answer (score 0):

Протестить не могу, но примерно так

```
 mess_id, mess_chat = message.id, message.chat.id
 r_peer = await app.resolve_peer(mess_chat)
 print(await app.invoke(GetMessageReactionsList(peer=r_peer, id=mess_id, limit=-1)))
```

Comment: А, прошу прощения, перечитал доку. Кто ставит реакцию узнать через Pyrogram, видимо, не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Для использования метода GetMessagesReactions в pyrogram необходимо создать объект класса `pyrogram.raw.functions.messages.GetReactions`, который соответствует данному RPC-запросу. Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией `pyrogram.raw.functions.messages.GetReactions` и передать ей в качестве аргументов `peer` и `id` соответствующие значения.

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.raw.functions.messages import GetReactions
from pyrogram.types import InputPeerChat

# создаем клиента
app = Client("my_account")

# получаем chat_id
chat_id = 100123456789

# получаем peer объект
peer = InputPeerChat(chat_id)

# идентификатор сообщения, для которого нужно получить реакции
message_id = 12345

# создаем объект запроса
request = GetReactions(peer=peer, msg_id=message_id, offset=0, limit=100)

# отправляем запрос
result = app.send(request)

# получаем список пользователей, которые поставили реакцию
users = result.users
print(users)
```

Также можно воспользоваться методом `app.get_messages` для получения сообщения, для которого необходимо получить реакции, и методом `message.get_reactions` для получения списка пользователей, которые поставили реакцию.

```
from pyrogram import Client

# создаем клиента
app = Client("my_account")

# получаем chat_id
chat_id = 100123456789

# получаем сообщение
message = app.get_messages(chat_id, message_id=12345)

# получаем список пользователей, которые поставили реакцию
users = message.get_reactions("")
print(users)
```

Обратите внимание, что метод `message.get_reactions` возвращает список объектов класса `pyrogram.types.User`. Если нужно получить список ID пользователей, можно воспользоваться списковым выражением:

```
user_ids = [user.id for user in users]
print(user_ids)
```

Но, учитывая, что получение реакций для всех сообщений в группе может быть довольно ресурсоемкой операцией, рекомендую использовать официальный Telegram API и платный сервис [Telegram Analytics](https://tgstat.ru/).